# How to auto-scale to different screen resolutions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, resolution

I'm making an infinite runner in unity, I have an tile spawner/generator and its generating GameObjects based on screen height and width, I managed to make it work with the width but when changing the height the camera doesn't follow and I can't manage to make that work.

Anyway, my code isn't good, I have spent the last 6 hours into that and I don't appreciate the result.

As I found out you can define an aspect ratio to the camera and it will auto-scale your ratio to that one, but it distorts the image and doesn't look great.

Since all those notes, which is the best way to auto-scale a 2D platform game (NOT CONSIDERING GUI, only GameObjects)

Answer (score 1):

I' m using this script to stretch sprites based on their size, works for most cases. I use 5 for the orthographicSize of camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[ExecuteInEditMode]
#endif
public class SpriteStretch : MonoBehaviour {
    public enum Stretch{Horizontal, Vertical, Both};
    public Stretch stretchDirection = Stretch.Horizontal;
    public Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0f,0f);

    SpriteRenderer sprite;
    Transform _thisTransform;


    void Start () 
    {
        _thisTransform = transform;
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        StartCoroutine("stretch");
    }
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    void Update()
    {
        scale();
    }
    #endif
    IEnumerator stretch()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        scale();
    }
    void scale()
    {
        float worldScreenHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize *2f;
        float worldScreenWidth = worldScreenHeight / Screen.height * Screen.width;
        float ratioScale = worldScreenWidth / sprite.sprite.bounds.size.x;
        ratioScale += offset.x;
        float h = worldScreenHeight /  sprite.sprite.bounds.size.y;
        h += offset.y;
        switch(stretchDirection)
        {
        case Stretch.Horizontal:
            _thisTransform.localScale = new Vector3(ratioScale,_thisTransform.localScale.y,_thisTransform.localScale.z);
            break;
        case Stretch.Vertical:
            _thisTransform.localScale = new Vector3(_thisTransform.localScale.x, h,_thisTransform.localScale.z);
            break;
        case Stretch.Both:
            _thisTransform.localScale = new Vector3(ratioScale, h,_thisTransform.localScale.z);
            break;
        default:break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First i want to say there are no good solutions only less bad.

The easiest is to just support one aspect ratio that way you can just scale everything up and down without distortion but that almost never an option.

The second easiest is to make the game be in one aspect ratio and add black bars (or something) to the edges to made the actual game area the same aspect ratio.

If you still want different aspect ratios the solution is to increase the game area but that might cause people with different aspect ratios to get an advantage since they can see further ahead or higher and it might mess up your level design.

I just posted an answer to how make everything work automatically as long as you have constant aspect ration here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25160299/2885785